# Draw custom Arc shape flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to draw this kind of shape with flutter:
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdjXo.png)

So far I can draw an arc using drawArc():

```
class CurvePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.green;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    paint.strokeWidth = 5;

    final rect = Rect.fromLTRB(50, 100, 130, 200);
    final startAngle = -pi;
    final sweepAngle = pi;
    canvas.drawArc(rect, startAngle, sweepAngle, false, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

But is that the right way to do it or should I use quadraticBezierTo and drawPath?

Comment: I think look at this library can help you.. https://github.com/rafalbednarczuk/curved_navigation_bar

Comment: https://github.com/rafalbednarczuk/curved_navigation_bar/blob/master/lib/src/nav_custom_painter.dart